# Simple MDX Date Range not Working

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have this:

```
 SELECT 
   {[Case_Type].[Case_Type].AllMembers} ON COLUMNS,
   {[Geography].[country].AllMembers} ON ROWS 
 FROM [Cases_Cube]
 where ([Create_Date_Key].[Create_Date_Key].&[20150201] :  [Create_Date_Key].[Create_Date_Key].&[20150208])
```

and it works fine - IF there is a 20150201 and 20150208 respectively.

However, I need to be able to send in ANY date range. When I use a date that is not there...  the query fails.

I have done a lot of research and can't seem to get a good, simple, answer.

Comment: Where is the query going to feed from? Is there any reporting interface from where you would pass the two, say "start date" and "end date"?

Answer (score 0):

This is the troublesome set?

`[Create_Date_Key].[Create_Date_Key].&[20150201] :  [Create_Date_Key].[Create_Date_Key].&[20150208]`

If `20150201` does not exist in the cube the processor will interpret the above as the following:

`null :  [Create_Date_Key].[Create_Date_Key].&[20150208]`

Which returns all dates up to 20150208

If `20150208` does not exist in the cube the processor will interpret the above as the following:

`[Create_Date_Key].[Create_Date_Key].&[20150201] :  null`

Which returns all dates after to 20150201.

Hopefully this explains the behaviour you are experiencing.

Can you limit the user's choice to dates that exist in your cube?

Comment: Yes, that explains the behaviour.  But no, I cannot limit the choices,  the query parameters are coming from another system.

Comment: ok - somehow your query need to move to the nearest existing date - I'm unsure of the standard approach to solve this. @GregGalloway - how should the user approach this common problem?

Comment: @mmaceachran ok - one idea would be to use a custom measure that gets the keys of the input dates and then uses the `Filter` function to return the set of target dates, whose keys are greater than or less than your two limiting dates.